# What is the flow on effect of Haneda and Narita flight cancellations?

Tags: air-travel, japan, cancellations, delays

There is a big typhoon in Central Japan that has cause flight cancellation of ANA and JAL and cancellations/indefinite delays for nearly all other airlines. My parents are travelling from Perth on 14th October at night (10 pm). Assuming there is flight cancellations for all of 12th October but no longer than that day, based on history what sort of flow on effects should we expect on such as flight delays?

Update: ANA cancelled all flights for the 13th as well and similarly for all airlines.

Answer (score 6):

Expect delay and potential schedule changes. Carefully monitor the airline's website, notifications and flight status.

This may all just work as planned but there is a chance of disruption so it's important to stay closely in the loop. A colleague of mine is currently stranded in Japan: they were supposed to return today but didn't get a new return flight until Wednesday.

All flights will be full so make sure you check in as early as possible to secure your seats and deal with any things that may go wrong. Airline staff will be stressed and tired so mistakes can happen.

Some airlines also allow free changes. If your parents are open to stay a little longer they may be able to change their schedules without charge and then reschedule to a time where things are back to normal.

Comment: They come from Perth so it is likely to be a shorter stay- no big deal since it is 15 days for seeing my grandchild but they are staying at a weekly mansion so it has only business hours check in unless we help- it is local for us. ANA has not informed them of any potential delays. How long might the delays be?